# Trying to simplify reading in csv and array initialization into numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I am new to using Numpy. I am trying to simplify reading in features and setting initializing my numpy arrays.

I want the feature_name to contain all features for columns 0-4,  _X to contain all rows and columns 0 - 4 and _y to contain all rows for column 5.

My code works, but its not as succinct or understandable as I would like it to be

```
import csv 
import numpy as np

# read in the data as rows 
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile: 
    _reader = csv.reader( csvfile, delimiter =',',quotechar ='"') 

    # Read in the feature names into an array
    feature_names = _reader.next() 

    # Read the in the sample data
    _X, _y = [], []
    for row in _reader: 
        _X.append( row ) #read in plant  
        _y.append( row[ 5]) 

feature_names = np.array(feature_names) 
_X      = np.array( _X) 
_y      = np.array( _y)

_X = _X[:, [0,1,2,3,4]] 
_names = feature_names[[ 0,1,2,3,4]]
```

I really appreciate your assistance and want to improve my coding! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are re-implementing the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) package. Specifically, 
[`pandas.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html), 
and `pandas.DataFrame`. See [10 minutes of pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html).

You can also use `numpy.genfromtxt()`.

Comment: Thanks cyborg, I need to get things into numpy arrays as parametrs for random forests, I never used pandas and may not have it available to me. I appreciate any further suggestions

Comment: I tried using it, but it is not array of float any more ....(12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0), (18.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
       (31.194181, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)], 
      dtype=[('Number_of_spines', '<f8'), ('Colors', '<f8'), ('toothed', '<f8'), ('toothless', '<f8'), ('lobed', '<f8'), ('Poisonous', '<f8')])